# Is it possible to put shared IIS configuration on a network drive?

Tags: iis-7

Is it possible to put shared IIS 7 configuration on a network drive?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of network drive? A samba share?

As long as the share comes up before IIS does, there *shouldn't* be a problem.

However, if IIS starts before the share becomes available, or the share disappears during operation, IIS will hang.